# Display Background color in print page

Tags: php, javascript, css, printing

I am using javascript:print() for taking print in PHP script.I added the background color in that.Actually it will be dynamic background color.While seeing the print preview the background color is not coming.Kindly anyone help in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set css `media` attribute?

Comment: why would anyone want to waste ink on bgcolor?

Comment: @Zaffy ya i set type as media in css.But still didnt get

Comment: @Gordon maybe he want to print to pdf or something...

Comment: -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; /* Webkit only - obviously */

Comment: @h0tw1r3 where i can use your script in my page.Kindly explain it.

Comment: It would be much kinder to use a print-only stylesheet to force all text to black and all backgrounds to white.

Answer (score 2):

You can not control this via javascript.

The user may enable printing of background images or color in the printer dialog.

Comment: How I enable this option.Kindly explain it.

Comment: @Hariprabu You cannot, it is a browser setting you have no control over.

Comment: @jeroen Is there any way to set without browser setting.

Comment: it's OS dependent,. here on ubuntu I switch to the "Options" tab in the printer dialog and then may enable one or both of the options. :) The website can not enforce this setting, OS independent!

Comment: @jeroen any idea about -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;

Answer (score 0):

Although @Jan.'s answer is correct and you should not mess with the users preferences and settings, it is technically possible.

Just position an element behind all of your content and put an image in it having your desired background color that stretches to 100% width and 100% height. Using javascript / css this would be pretty easy.

It will annoy (to put it mildly...) people who print the page though...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea about  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; Kindly explain this one.Is this possible?